# Locate date within a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I'm trying to locate a specific date within a column of a DataFrame using the df.loc function but I suddenly started getting a KeyError. This method has always worked for me but somehow, it throws a KeyError on this specific problem.

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt


x = pd.read_csv('x_data.csv')

# x
#   type      date   color
# 0    A  10/16/18  orange
# 1    B  10/15/18     red
# 2    C  10/12/18    blue


x['date'] = x['date'].apply(lambda xl: datetime.datetime.strptime(xl, '%m/%d/%y'))
x['date'] = x['date'].apply(lambda xl: datetime.datetime.strftime(xl, '%Y-%m-%d'))
d = '2018-10-15'

# x
#   type        date   color
# 0    A  2018-10-16  orange
# 1    B  2018-10-15     red
# 2    C  2018-10-12    blue
```

I then try to use df.loc to locate `d` within the `date` column with the following line:

```
x = x.loc[x['date']] == d
```

Which returns error:

```
KeyError: 'None of [0    2018-10-16\n1    2018-10-15\n2    2018-10-12\nName: date, dtype: object] are in the [index]'
```

I cannot figure this problem out because I have been using this method for a while for various datasets a have never encountered a problem until now.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: don't you want `x = x.loc[x['date'] == d]`? you seem to have a misplaced square bracket

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. My bad.